# c++ Как создать программой конфигурационный файл и читать из него параметры

Tags: c++, configuration

Как в c++ можно создать типо конфигурационный файл в который можно как записывать, так и читать информацию?

Comment: Встроенных средств нет. Но можно парсить самому, или подключить стороную либу.

Comment: Какую можете посоветовать?

Comment: https://github.com/nlohmann/json эту. Если у вас есть boost: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/874a0d2d96f4c651

Comment: Смотря какой Си. В С++Builder имеется класс INI_файлов. В С# тоже имеется кое-что.

Answer (score 1):

Проще использовать кусок [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/property_tree.html), там весь код для конфигов, кстати, в заголовках, сборки буста не нужно. Поддерживает три общеупотребительных формата, плюс один свой... Свой компактный, хорошо читаемый... но совсем свой :)